# Merge two columns into one from the same table

Tags: r

So, I'd like to merge two columns in one. 
That's how my data looks like:

```
> tbl_end

Sequence                                 modifications                  no_Ks      no_Ks_modif           V1
AAAAGAAAVANQGKK               [14] Acetyl (K)|[15] Acetyl (K)             2           2              [14] Acetyl 
AAAAGAAAVANQGKK               [14] Acetyl (K)|[15] Acetyl (K)             2           2              [14] Acetyl 
AAFTKLDQVWGSE                                [5] Acetyl (K)               1           1              [5] Acetyl 
AAIKFIKFINPKINDGE   [4] Acetyl (K)|[7] Acetyl (K)|[12] Acetyl (K)         3           3              [4] Acetyl 
AAIKFIKFINPKINDGE   [4] Acetyl (K)|[7] Acetyl (K)|[12] Acetyl (K)         3           3              [4] Acetyl
```

I'd like to merge columns Sequence and modifications without disturbing other dataset.

The name of new column may be "Seq_modif"

Tried to do it with paste but it's not what I am looking for:

```
tbl_reo2 <- paste(tbl_end$Sequence,tbl_end$modifications)
```

so that's what I'd like to achieve by the script:

```
              Seq_modif                                                no_Ks      no_Ks_modif         V1
AAAAGAAAVANQGKK [14] Acetyl (K)|[15] Acetyl (K)                           2           2              [14] Acetyl 
AAAAGAAAVANQGKK [14] Acetyl (K)|[15] Acetyl (K)                           2           2              [14] Acetyl 
AAFTKLDQVWGSE [5] Acetyl (K)                                              1           1              [5] Acetyl 
AAIKFIKFINPKINDGE [4] Acetyl (K)|[7] Acetyl (K)|[12] Acetyl (K)           3           3              [4] Acetyl 
AAIKFIKFINPKINDGE [4] Acetyl (K)|[7] Acetyl (K)|[12] Acetyl (K)           3           3              [4] Acetyl
```

Comment: I mean that there is a way to do it with paste and it will be like 10 lines of code and I am pretty sure that's possible to do in one line.

Comment: Maybe, `tbl_end$Seq_modif <- paste(tbl_end$Sequence, tbl_end$modifications, sep = " _ ")`?

Comment: Explain why it is not what you are looking for. Or tell us exactly what you are looking for. For example, you could tell us what the first value (first row) in `Seq_modif` should be.

Comment: Already edited what I expect to get. Thought that I already explained it in the text. It wasn't necessary to updown it.

Comment: You could create a new dataframe as: `tbl_reo2 <- data.frame(Seq_modif = paste(tbl_end$Sequence, tbl_end$modifications, sep = " "), no_Ks = tbl_end$no_Ks, no_ks_modif = tbl_end$no_Ks_modif, V1 = tbl_end$V1, stringsAsFactors = F)`

Answer (score 4):

Try this way. I'm not so good with R but it should work. I think that's better to help instead of vote the topic down.

Here you are:

```
tbl_end$Seq_modif <- paste(tbl_end$Sequence, tbl_end$modifications)

tbl_end[, "Seq_modif"] <- tbl_end$Seq_modif

tbl_end <- subset(tbl_end, select = -c(Sequence,modifications) )
```

Comment: Thanks. It works fine for me. Time to delete the account from this forum.